# Можно ли строку (с числами и арифметическими операторами) посчитать без условий в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример того, что я хочу

```
string = input() # Ввожу + или - или / или *

print(10 string 10)
```

На выходе должен быть результат в виде ответа в зависимости от символа.
1.Почему бы не сделать через условия спросите вы? Представьте что я не знаю, сколько введет пользователь арифметических операторов и переменных с числами, но это надо посчитать согласно математике. Как это делает Python

2.Или через циклы это все сделать и назначить что, после чего должно выполняться сначала с (+, -) потом (*, /)?

*Но зачем изобретать велосипед чтобы покататься, если его уже изобрели. Вы просто научите кататься)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

способ 1 (для сильных духом):

```
text = input("введите выражение:");

print(f"{text} = {eval(text)}")
```

Если же вы хотите делать самостоятельно `но это надо посчитать согласно математике`, то надо много чего учитывать - скобки к примеру и т.д.

Но считаем, что доступны только арифметические операции и все, тогда надо всего лишь учитывать приоритет операций :)

Если и это не учитывать, то код будет таким:

```
text = input("введите выражение:");

res = 0

action = '+'

actions = {
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a * b,
    '/': lambda a, b: a / b,
}

for obj in text.split():
    if obj in '+-*/':
        action = obj
    else:
        res = actions[action](res, int(obj))

print(res)
```

тут у операций одинаковый приоритет, но можно чуть дописать код и сделать * и / более приоритетными, правда тогда надо будет и рекурсивный вызов добавить

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек)

Comment: 1 способ идеальный, так как если мне нужно посчитать допустим косинус то я могу применить find("cos") в переменной и применить функцию косинуса и потом заменить выражение на ответ с косинусом и уже потом подставить в функцию eval(). Большое спасибо

Comment: @NIGVUL, только не давайте как у меня в примере доступ пользователя к `eval`, а то вместо формулы можно и алгоритм по изъятию всех денег ввести :)

Comment: А не подскажите как? :) Я уже прочитал с помощью этой функции можно и файлы все удалить, если os импортирована. У меня обычный калькулятор с числами и операторами, пользователю полной свободы не дается.

Comment: `eval` исполняет код, так что если можете написать код на питоне который что-то делает, так и если этот код передать как строку в `eval` будет тоже самое

Comment: А есть ли возможность именно преобразование в математическое решение, а не кража файлов, денег и другого) Чтобы было ограничено?

Comment: @NIGVUL, ну надо проверить выражение на то, что оно не содержит ничего кроме цифр, математических действий и т.п.

Comment: В идеале писать собственный парсер, который будет пропускать только математические операции.